# Keeping JTable selection

Tags: java, swing, jtable, selectionmodel

I am using `JTable` with `MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION` when I call

```
 int[] selectedRows = jtable.getSelectedRows();
```

I am getting array of selected rows indexes like `5,6,8` for eg. Now In case of error I want to maintain same selection.

I am trying

```
_selectionModel.setSelectionInterval(selectedRows[0], selectedRows[selectedRows.length-1]);
```

but it is selecting rows from 5 to 8 how can I avoid to select row number 7 which wasn't selected before?

Comment: Why don't you use just use a for loop and select each Row separate? Or isn't it possible to use the int-array directly with another method?

Comment: I'm not sure, didn't find any method apart from this.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < selectedRowCount; i++)
       {
           table.changeSelection(selectedRows[i], 1, true, false);
       }

How about this?

Comment: let me check for this.

Comment: Ehm also better use table.clearSelection(); before using changeSelection().

Comment: not working, it goes back and select first row.

Comment: weird, worked for me though.

Comment: @LeoPflug its working for me in test application but not in my main application, any  suggestion?

Comment: Do not change things at the table(delete rows, add rows) after changeSelection is used. showing us a bigger codesnippet should do the trick :P

Answer (score 3):

For that purposes you can use [`addSelectionInterval()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListSelectionModel.html#addSelectionInterval%28int,%20int%29) method instead of `setSelectionInterval()`. For example:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class Example  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JTable t = new JTable(10,1);
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(t));

        t.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
        t.getSelectionModel().addSelectionInterval(5, 6);
        t.getSelectionModel().addSelectionInterval(8, 8);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Its working in test application but not in my main application any problem?

Comment: Post code example of your problem, seems you have a specific problem.